# "could not authenticate" with promised-mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication

I am using [Promised-Mongo](https://github.com/gordonmleigh/promised-mongo) to connect MongoDB with Promises from NodeJS backend code. It worked fine, until I enabled MongoDB's client access control. When I run this code, I get "could not authenticate" message":

```
var pmongo = require('promised-mongo').compatible();
var db = pmongo('myusername:mypassword@localhost/mydb', ['candidates']);
db.candidates.save(req.body)
    .then(function () {
        // never reached here
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        // it reached here, where e.message says "could not authenticate"
    });
```

Pure MongoDB code (i.e. no Promises...) works fine:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var uri = 'mongodb://myusername:mypassword@localhost/mydb'; 
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        // never reached here
    }
    var candidates = db.collection('candidates');
    candidates.insert(req.body, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
        // never reached here
        }
        res.send('{result: success}');
    });
});
```

Any idea?

Comment: connect now, and worry about collections later
var db = pmongo('mydb'); From docs.. Hope this helps

Comment: tried it already, didn't work...

Comment: Am..from you message   where e.message says "could not authenticate"...this is the problem. Check credentials for mongodb. Do you have all access rights. And try to connect with same credential using mongo shell.

Comment: Like this mongo -u <user> -p <pass> --authenticationDatabase yourAuthDB

Comment: I used the second snippet of code (that works) to "prove" it's not a problem of wrong credentials. mongo shell also works for me. It's something with the save() method (or something I missed before that), but I just can't figure out what exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per several issues in the github repository (see [here](https://github.com/gordonmleigh/promised-mongo/issues/53) and [here](https://github.com/gordonmleigh/promised-mongo/issues/35)) it looks like using this library with authentication is totally broken. Per the second link, most people seem to be wrapping the official library with a promise via something like promisify, bluebird, or a thin custom wrapper.